# Problem Installing tximportData on R: What is this error about?

Tags: r

I am trying to install tximportData package using this command:

This is the error I get, not sure what I do wrong. I have also attached sessionInfo()

```
if (!requireNamespace("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE))
  install.packages("BiocManager")

BiocManager::install("tximportData")



> if (!requireNamespace("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE))
+   install.packages("BiocManager")
> 
> BiocManager::install("tximportData") Bioconductor version 3.12 (BiocManager 1.30.10), R 4.0.3   (2020-10-10) Installing package(s) 'tximportData' installing the source package ‘tximportData’

trying URL 'https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.12/data/experiment/src/contrib/tximportData_1.18.0.tar.gz' Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 426787346 bytes (407.0 MB)
======================= downloaded 191.7 MB

Error in download.file(url, destfile, method, mode = "wb", ...) :    download from 'https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.12/data/experiment/src/contrib/tximportData_1.18.0.tar.gz' failed Warning in download.packages(pkgs, destdir = tmpd, available = available,  :   download of package ‘tximportData’ failed
> library("tximportData") Error in library("tximportData") :    there is no package called ‘tximportData’
> ##################################Run-Separetly
> if (!requireNamespace("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE))
+   install.packages("BiocManager")
> 
> BiocManager::install("tximportData") Bioconductor version 3.12 (BiocManager 1.30.10), R 4.0.3   (2020-10-10) Installing package(s) 'tximportData' installing the source package ‘tximportData’

trying URL 'https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.12/data/experiment/src/contrib/tximportData_1.18.0.tar.gz' Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 426787346 bytes (407.0 MB)
======================== downloaded 201.5 MB

Error in download.file(url, destfile, method, mode = "wb", ...) :    download from 'https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.12/data/experiment/src/contrib/tximportData_1.18.0.tar.gz' failed Warning in download.packages(pkgs, destdir = tmpd, available = available,  :   download of package ‘tximportData’ failed
> sessionInfo() R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10) Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit) Running under: macOS Catalina 10.15.7

Matrix products: default BLAS:   /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale: [1] en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/C/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8

attached base packages: [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   [7] base     

other attached packages: [1] tximport_1.18.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached): [1] BiocManager_1.30.10 compiler_4.0.3      assertthat_0.2.1    [4] cli_2.1.0           tools_4.0.3         glue_1.4.2          [7] rstudioapi_0.11     crayon_1.3.4        fansi_0.4.1        
>
```

Comment: Could you perhaps try installing `tximportData` in a fresh `R` session?

Comment: Hi, I thought I am installing already since I used that:
BiocManager::install("tximportData") Bioconductor version 3.12 (BiocManager 1.30.10), R 4.0.3   (2020-10-10) Installing package(s) 'tximportData' installing the source package ‘tximportData’
How do I actually install ??

Answer (score 0):

I tried installing `tximportData` like you did using `R 4.0.3` and ended up with the same result. It appears that for reasons not fully clear the download (and subsequently installation) fails:

```
> BiocManager::install("tximportData")
Bioconductor version 3.12 (BiocManager 1.30.10), R 4.0.3 (2020-10-10)
Installing package(s) 'tximportData'
trying URL 'https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.12/data/experiment/src/contrib/tximportData_1.18.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 426787346 bytes (407.0 MB)
========================================
downloaded 333.1 MB

Error in download.file(url, destfile, method, mode = "wb", ...) : 
  download from 'https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.12/data/experiment/src/contrib/tximportData_1.18.0.tar.gz' failed
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In download.file(url, destfile, method, mode = "wb", ...) :
  downloaded length 349322808 != reported length 426787346
2: In download.file(url, destfile, method, mode = "wb", ...) :
  URL 'https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.12/data/experiment/src/contrib/tximportData_1.18.0.tar.gz': Timeout of 60 seconds was reached
Warning in download.packages(pkgs, destdir = tmpd, available = available,  :
  download of package ‘tximportData’ failed
```

But the actual source file of the package itself (`https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.12/data/experiment/src/contrib/tximportData_1.18.0.tar.gz`; see the code snippet above) downloads just fine outside of `R` (should be 407MB in size).

So I propose you simply download this file (using a web browser, `curl`, or `wget`) and install the package manually.

If you're working in `RStudio` just click on `Install` under the `Packages` pane, and under `Install from:` select `Package Archive File (.tar.gz)` from the drop down menu in the `Install Packages` dialog box that pops up. Selecting that option should automatically open your file explorer wherein you can then navigate to the downloaded file and select it (otherwise, just click on the `Browse` button in the `Install Packages` dialog box. Click `Install` to install the package.

If you're working in `R` from the commandline use `install.packages(mypath, repos = NULL, type = "source")` to install the package; here the variable `mypath` should contain the path to location of the downloaded file (e.g., `mypath <- "/path/to/tximportData_1.18.0.tar.gz"`). (You can do this in RStudio too, of course.)

The manual installation should work fine.